# Python version can't be changed in the command line

Tags: python, command-line, path, version

Why does my PATH settings have no influence on the default python version in the command line?

I have two versions of python installed: 3.11 and 3.9 (Windows 10)
[Available python versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIk22.jpg)

As you can see the default python version is 3.9. I want to change this. 3.11 should be my default version.
According to my system environment variables path settings 3.11 should be the default python version:
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8tEK.jpg)

Why doesn't PATH have an influence on the default version? And what can I try in addition to the PATH settings?

*Edit1: I today deleted the 3.9 python version from the environment variables. Python 3.11 is at the beginning of the list now. And there is no other version of python on this list. The result is that if I use the command line prompt, it still shows me the 3.9 version*

Answer (score 0):

1 Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables" and click on "Edit the system environment variables".

2 In the System Properties window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.

3 In the Environment Variables window, scroll down to find the "Path" variable under System Variables and click on "Edit".

4 In the Edit Environment Variable window, add the directory containing python.exe for Python 3.11 **at the beginning of the list**, followed by a semicolon (;). For example: C:\Program Files\Python311;C:\Program Files\Python39; (make sure to replace the directories with the correct paths on your system).

5 Click "OK" to close all windows and restart the command prompt.

After following these steps, running python in the command prompt should use the version of Python 3.11 that you installed in the directory you specified.

Comment: This doesn't work. As you can see on my second picture, the correct path was already there. I deleted the first two entries now. Closed the windows and added them back with the steps you suggested, but I still get 3.9.10 as version.